# User fields not showing up after adding "Flags: User" relationship in Views

Tags: 7, views

**Question: How can I get Flags: User fields to be added to my view table?**

Can't figure out why after adding the Flags: User relationship (in addition to the Flags: Node relation) that I still can't add Flags: User fields to my view.

I've googled and search d.se, but no one else seems to be having this problem.

My flag export is:

```
$flags = array();
// Exported flag: "Response is out of date or needs revision".
$flags['response_needs_revision'] = array(
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'title' => 'Response is out of date or needs revision',
  'global' => 1,
  'types' => array(
    0 => 'question',
  ),
  'flag_short' => 'Flag response as needing revision',
  'flag_long' => '',
  'flag_message' => 'Thank you for letting us know! An email has been sent to the team responsible for this question.',
  'unflag_short' => 'Unflag this response',
  'unflag_long' => '',
  'unflag_message' => 'Thanks! This response has been unflagged.',
  'unflag_denied_text' => 'This RFP response has already been flagged. ',
  'link_type' => 'confirm',
  'weight' => 0,
  'show_in_links' => array(
    'full' => 0,
    'teaser' => 0,
    'rss' => 0,
    'search_index' => 0,
    'search_result' => 0,
    'token' => 0,
    'workflow_tab' => 0,
    'revision' => 0,
  ),
  'show_as_field' => 1,
  'show_on_form' => 0,
  'access_author' => '',
  'show_contextual_link' => 0,
  'i18n' => 0,
  'flag_confirmation' => 'How can this response be improved?',
  'unflag_confirmation' => 'Better now?',
  'api_version' => 3,
);
return $flags;
```

My view screenshot:

[image: View Screenshot]
[image: flag relationship]
[image: flag user]
[image: flag fields available]

Raw export:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'workbench_moderation';
$view->description = 'Lists content by moderation state.';
$view->tag = 'Moderation';
$view->base_table = 'node_revision';
$view->human_name = 'Moderation Panel';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Content I\'ve edited';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'view all';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  11 => '11',
  8 => '8',
  10 => '10',
  9 => '9',
  6 => '6',
  4 => '4',
  5 => '5',
  7 => '7',
  3 => '3',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['expose']['items_per_page'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['expose']['items_per_page_options'] = '10, 25, 50, 100, 200';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'nid' => 'nid',
  'title' => 'title',
  'field_category_term' => 'field_category_term',
  'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
  'mail' => 'mail',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'nid' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_category_term' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'timestamp' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'mail' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Header: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['label'] = 'Instructions';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['content'] = 'This is a test message.';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'You haven\'t created or edited any content.';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = '1';
/* Relationship: Content revision: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['id'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['field'] = 'vid';
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['relationship'] = 'vid';
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['link_to_node'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Category */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['id'] = 'field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['table'] = 'field_data_field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['field'] = 'field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['relationship'] = 'vid';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Requester';
/* Field: Content: Response requested by */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_response_requested_by']['id'] = 'field_response_requested_by';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_response_requested_by']['table'] = 'field_data_field_response_requested_by';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_response_requested_by']['field'] = 'field_response_requested_by';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_response_requested_by']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_response_requested_by']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'short',
  'custom_date_format' => '',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 1,
);
/* Field: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Filter criterion: User: Current */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['id'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['field'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['value'] = '1';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['label'] = 'Title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['label'] = 'Type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['identifier'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Broken/missing handler */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['id'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['table'] = 'workbench_moderation_node_history';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['field'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['value'] = array(
  'all' => 'all',
  'draft' => 'draft',
  'needs_review' => 'needs_review',
  'published' => 'published',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'state_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['expose']['label'] = 'State';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['expose']['operator'] = 'state_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['expose']['identifier'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Broken/missing handler */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_current']['id'] = 'is_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_current']['table'] = 'workbench_moderation_node_history';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['is_current']['field'] = 'is_current';

/* Display: Flagged for Review */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Flagged for Review', 'needs_review_page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Flagged for Review';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['access'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  11 => '11',
  8 => '8',
  10 => '10',
  9 => '9',
  6 => '6',
  4 => '4',
  5 => '5',
  7 => '7',
  3 => '3',
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['empty'] = FALSE;
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'This list displays content that has been flagged for additional review for you to moderate. Currently there is no such content.';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'plain_text';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: Content revision: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['id'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['table'] = 'node_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['vid']['field'] = 'vid';
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['relationship'] = 'vid';
/* Relationship: Flags: response_needs_revision */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'response_needs_revision';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['user_scope'] = 'any';
/* Relationship: Flags: User */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_1']['id'] = 'uid_1';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_1']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_1']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid_1']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['link_to_node'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Flagging: Additional details */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_additional_details']['id'] = 'field_additional_details';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_additional_details']['table'] = 'field_data_field_additional_details';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_additional_details']['field'] = 'field_additional_details';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_additional_details']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_additional_details']['label'] = 'Details';
/* Field: Content: Category */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['id'] = 'field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['table'] = 'field_data_field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['field'] = 'field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_category_term']['relationship'] = 'vid';
/* Field: Flags: Flagged time */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = 'Date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['label'] = 'Title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'question' => 'question',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['label'] = 'Type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['identifier'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Category (field_category_term) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['id'] = 'field_category_term_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_category_term';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['field'] = 'field_category_term_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['relationship'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['value'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_category_term_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['expose']['label'] = 'Category';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_category_term_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_category_term_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 0,
  11 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_category_term_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'category';
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'admin/workbench/needs-review';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Flagged for Review';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '99';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
```

Comment: I'd rather see View screenshot than export.

Comment: Sorry, screenshots now added.